# OS X 10.11 El Capitan Black Screen

Tags: vmware, osx-elcapitan

I installed OS X 10.11 El Capitan on VMware and it worked successfully but after i shut it down and reopen , it got stuck after loading with apple logo and turns a black screen 
can anyone help me with this,Please ?
i run this VMware on Windows 10 ,Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to this [source](http://www.networkworld.com/article/3012241/macs/a-fix-for-the-os-x-black-screen-of-doom.html) who had the same problem you can follow these steps and see if it works:

1. Reboot to safe mode, here are the [steps](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21875?locale=en_GB).
2. Delete this file "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist"
3. Switch off iCloud authentication and revert to local authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 10.13 High Sierra

Editing my VMX file (*Documents/Virtual Machines/MacOS/MacOS.vmx*) to include:

```
virtualHW.version = "10"
```

Fixed it for me.